# How to get dried split peas to be equivalent to fresh peas

Tags: substitutions, cooking-time

I'm making Fresh Pea Soup, but I don't have fresh green peas. Instead, I have dried peas that I obtained from the bulk section at my local market.

The recipe asks for 4 cups of fresh green peas. In the recipe, they only need to be cooked for five minutes. I'm fairly certain that I wouldn't get the right consistency if I only cooked the dried peas for five minutes. How long should I soak, then boil the dried split peas for so that I can just treat them as fresh peas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way that dried peas are going to perform well in a recipe designed for fresh peas.  Instead, you should look for recipes that work with dried peas, such as the canonical split pea soup.